# Is there a way to 'script' a git commit - only accepting some diffs?

Tags: git, pre-commit

I have applied some static code analysis - and transformed all Java package level fields into protected. This is mostly correct, as I forgot to set the access modifier explicitly, and protected is generally what I was after in those cases.

Unfortunately, the refactoring I applied was the IntelliJ weaken access modifiers on, and it also changes lots of public -> protected, on constructors and so on.

So once I have a diff with statements like this in it:

```
-int myField;
+protected int myField;
```

and

```
-public MyConstructor()
+protected MyConstructor()
```

Is there a way to write a script, that runs during the commit, and only lets the first example above, but no the second? I can figure out the script, and I am just not sure how to run it - is it a pre-commit hook?

If its a pre-commit hook, how do you examine the diff in such a script and accept/reject it based on greping it for some string?

Answer (score 2):

Yep you can do it using smudge/filters

There are several ways to do it.

#### [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

git hooks is a script that run in a different phases of the git life-cycle.
In the proper hook file check the for the file/content that you need and do whatever you need with it.

The hook will run on your files and will check the syntax.

#### [Smudge/clean](https://github.com/gilesbowkett/git-smudge-and-clean)

Basically, smudge is equivalent to **run this code whenever you check anything out**
and clean is equivalent to **run this code whenever you check anything in**.

---

Images are from this url:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes

[image]